# Selenium Webdriver on RPI refusing connection from Crontab, works from terminal

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, firefox, raspberry-pi

I have a perfectly fine running python-script on my raspberry to open a website, navigate to a specific part, copy some text, save it and then compare it to something else.
It works great when I start it from the terminal.

But when I have it as a cronjob, it fails with the Message "The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details."
So the part, that is not working is:

```
from selenium import webdriver

try:
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

As you can see I did not specify a Log-path, because I honestly don't know how.
So if you can tell me that, I will gladly try to implement that and get the log.

Is there anything special you have to do, to get it started as a cronjob?
I call it with

```
*/1 * * * * root cd /home/pi/Desktop && sudo python WebAlert.py >> /var/log/myjob.log 2>&1
```

From the terminal it works with python `WebAlert.py`

Thank you very much guys, I'm out of ideas.

**EDIT**
I changed some lines.
I added this:
`binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/bin/iceweasel')`

and I changed the driver like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'/usr/local/bin/geckodriver', firefox_binary=binary)
```

Calling it in the crontab with this

```
cd /home/pi/Desktop && sudo ../../../usr/bin/python3 WebAlert.py >> /var/log/mylog.log
```

produces the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/pi/Desktop/WebAlert.py", line 37, in 
>       driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'/usr/local/bin/geckodriver', firefox_binary=binary)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in **init**
>       keep_alive=True)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in **init**
>       self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
>       response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following code before starting the driver solved my problem:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display 
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
display.start()
```